# WKWebView not calling navigation delegate methods

Tags: swift, uikit, webkit, wkwebview, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to export an html file as a pdf using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946461/uimarkuptextprintformatter-and-mac-catalyst) which uses a `WKWebView` to load an html string and then draw a PDF from that. I also need it to work on Catalyst, which is why I'm using this approach.

What's happening is that the `WKWebView` is never calling it's `navigationDelegate` methods. I've put a bunch of `print()` statements in a bunch of delegate methods but the only output I get is:

```
::::: SET WEBVIEW
Loaded
```

I can't figure out what is making the `WKWebView` not call it's delegate methods. I've also tried loading a URL like https://google.com and it fails the same way. I've even observed loading progress from the webview, and it is loading the content, just not calling the delegate.

I'd appreciate any help, I need this to work.

```swift
class ReportsRenderer: NSObject {

    var webView: WKWebView? = nil {
        didSet {
            print("::::: SET WEBVIEW")
        }
    }
    var completion: PDFCompletion!
    typealias PDFCompletion = (Result<NSData, Error>) -> Void
    
    func exportPDF(html: String, completion: @escaping PDFCompletion) throws {
        
        self.completion = completion
        
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        
        let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        webView?.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: baseURL)
        print("Loaded")

    }
    
    
    func createPDF(_ formatter: UIViewPrintFormatter) {
        print("Creating PDF")
        let printPageRenderer = UIPrintPageRenderer()
        printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(formatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
        
        let paperRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8)
        let padding: CGFloat = 20
        let printableRect = paperRect.insetBy(dx: padding, dy: padding)
        printPageRenderer.setValue(printableRect, forKey: "printableRect")
        printPageRenderer.setValue(paperRect, forKey: "paperRect")

        printPageRenderer.footerHeight = 70
        printPageRenderer.headerHeight = 20
        
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, .zero, nil)
        for i in 0..<printPageRenderer.numberOfPages {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            printPageRenderer.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
        
        self.completion?(.success(pdfData))
    }
}

extension ReportsRenderer: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("::::: WEBVIEW NAVIGATED")
        let viewPrintFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()
        createPDF(viewPrintFormatter)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("::::: WEBVIEW ERROR")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("::::: WEBVIEW DIDCOMMIT NAVIGATION")
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("::::: WEBVIEW didStartProvisionalNavigation")
    }
}
```

I'm calling it in my ViewController like:

```swift
do {
            try ReportsRenderer().exportPDF(html: string) { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let pdfData):
                    // ---- This is never called -----
                    print("Made the pdf data!")
                    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
                    let pdfFilename = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("\(UUID().uuidString).pdf")
                    pdfData.write(to: pdfFilename, atomically: true)

                case .failure(let error):
                    // ---- This is also never called -----
                    print("::::: Error")
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // There isn't an error here either
            print("::::: Error")
            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `ReportsRenderer` in `ViewController` to make it work. When you create an instance in `ViewController` it lives as long as the `ViewController` lives. In your case, it was getting deinitialized immediately.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let reportsRenderer = ReportsRenderer()
    // then...
    do {
        try reportsRenderer.exportPDF(html: string) { (result) in
    //...
}
```

Comment: When you create an instance on view controller it lives as long as the view controller lives. In your case, it was getting deinitialized immediately.